# setTimeout with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var timeOutID = 0;
   var checkScores = function() {
     $.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/countScoreCh'?>",
       success:function(response){
       if (response !=' ') {
         $('#scoreCh').html(response);
         clearTimeout(timeOutID);
       } else{
         timeOutID = setTimeout(checkScores, 3000);
       }
     });
   }
   timeOutID = setTimeout(checkScores,1000);
 </script>
```

I am using `setTimeout` if there is a change in the database. If there is a change..it will output the change.

My problem is `setTimeout` will only display the first call.and never checks again if there is another change in the database.

I don't know if `setTimeout` is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: I guess url: 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgCsProg/main/countScoreCh' will be fine. No need to wrap in php tag.

Comment: If no change in the database, what is the server response code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making these mistakes

1. If you want to poll for database changes, don't use `setTimeout`. Instead use `setInterval` and clear this interval depending upon your logic like after 50times or something else.
2. Use a busyFlag because you are making an `asynchronous` call. (As suggested by @mike)

Try this

```
var intervalId = null;
var IS_BUSY_FETCHING_UPDATES = false;

var checkScores = function() {
  if (!IS_BUSY_FETCHING_UPDTAES) {
    IS_BUSY_FETCHING_UPDTAES = true;

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/countScoreCh" 
    }).done(function(response){
      if (response) {
        $('#scoreCh').html(response);
      }
    }).fail(function(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }).always(function() {
      IS_BUSY_FETCHING_UPDATES = false; // This will be executed when AJAX gets complete
    });
}

intervalID = setInterval(checkScores,1000);
```

Comment: i understand now by using flag..but by following your suggestion..it will not display the changes..jst like nothing happens..

"if(!IS_BUSY_FETCHING_UPDATAES) = true; "(spelling) i dont know if you did that in purpose.. i change but the output will not display..:(

Comment: I removed PHP tag from the URL. Does that have to do anything ?

Comment: Can you use chrome debugger to see if you are getting response or not ? `Use console.log(response)` in done method to see what are you getting.

Comment: there is an error.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg//js/jquery.min.js
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input checkdbRequest:20

is that what you mean?

Comment: That means your server is not sending you the right response right ?

Comment: yeah...the server is not sending me the response.

Comment: Yeah then please fix that..:)

Comment: i think..i got it right now..:))
i dont know what i did is right or not.

i jst add "," at the end in
url: "http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/countScoreCh" 
it work..but when i check the debugger there is still no response..but the output already display on my page..even when there is update to the database.

Comment: Glad you could find out on your own. I think my answer helped you learn something on client side things. Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, setTimeout only runs once though.  You're looking for setInterval.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeOutID = 0;
    var checkScores = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/countScoreCh'?>",
            success: function(response) {
                if(response !== '') {
                    $('#scoreCh').html(response);
                }
            }
        });
    };
    timeOutID = setInterval(checkScores, 1000);
</script>
```

You could also get it working by just getting rid of that else in your success function:

```
success: function(response) {
    if(response !== '') {
        $('#scoreCh').html(response);
    }
    timeOutID = setTimeout(checkScores, 3000);
},
error: function() {
    timeOutID = setTimeout(checkScores, 3000);
}
```

Comment: +1 .Just don't use `clearInterval` otherwise it won't get executed next time. OP wants to listen for database changes everytime.

Comment: @blunderboy yeah, I was starting to think that might have been what he meant so I added the last suggestion.

Comment: No, you can not get it working by just removing else part. Consider whenever there is an error say Network error. Then you stop polling for database changes.

Comment: `setInterval` is the right way to do it and don't clear it. That's all  will solve OP's problem.

Comment: i still try remove else..xD

Comment: okay, yeah i was a little confused when I saw the cleartimeout, making me think he wanted to halt the request after receiving one.  woops, i'll update the answer.